# No JSON object could be decoded | AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell

So I've a simple script that deletes Cloudwatch alarms every month. However today I've noticed that I see No JSON object could be decoded error.

Reason was simple:

I have approximately 1500 Alarms with the name in below format

```
[Production-ALARM]-PING.Node+[10.0.0.0]-MAX-USAGE
```

I am aware that we need to add '[" at the start and "]' to delete such names. The talk is if I run the below command, it executes perfectly without any issue and deletes the respective alarm.

```
aws cloudwatch delete-alarms --alarm-name '["[Production-ALARM]-PING.Node+[10.0.0.0]-MAX-USAGE"]'
```

However, since the count of the alarms is quite high, I have the list of alarms as the text file with '[" "]' added, which I pass as parameter to a simple for loop in bash.

```
for clAlarmNames in `cat oldCloudwatchAlarms`
do
   #echo ${clAlarmNames}
   aws cloudwatch delete-alarms --alarm-names "${clAlarmNames}"
done
```

Input File Format: oldCloudwatchAlarms (there is no extension to the file)

**Sample Content of the file: The below is an example of the content**

```
'["[AB:Production-ALARM]-CLI.Node+[10.0.0.1]-Alert"]'
'["[AB:Production-ALARM]-GLI.Node+[10.0.0.2]-Alert"]'
```

However, it is not deleting the alarms as expected.

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). The right way to read a file in bash line-by-line is given in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: What's the *precise* format of your file? Don't just describe it in English -- give us a few lines as examples.

Comment: That said, why don't you just pass *all* the names to `aws cloudwatch delete-alarms` at once?

Comment: Loop is added, to print the deleting alarms which are then stored for future references.

Comment: so the goal is to have fine granularity? Because otherwise I don't see why you don't delete all N alarms at once, and then add all N to your records of what you deleted at the same time.

Comment: `'["[AB:Production-ALARM]-CLI.Node+[10.0.0.1]-Alert"]'` is invalid for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You can't treat literal quotes as a replacement for syntactic quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixing The Problem Narrowly

Delete the syntactic quotes from your file. That is to say, change it from:

```
'["[AB:Production-ALARM]-CLI.Node+[10.0.0.1]-Alert"]'
```

to:

```
["[AB:Production-ALARM]-CLI.Node+[10.0.0.1]-Alert"]
```

...after which you'll be able to run:

```
while IFS= read -r alarm_name_json; do
  aws cloudwatch delete-alarms --alarm-name "$alarm_name_json" </dev/null
done <file.txt
```

Quotes *in your data* are what we call "literal quotes". They're data, not shell syntax. Quotes *that are part of your code* are what we call "syntactic quotes"; they tell the shell how to parse other content in the code.

Adding extra quotes to your data can't substitute for missing syntactic quotes, because any quote you add to your data is *literal*, not *syntactic*.

---

#### Deleting All Alarms At Once

If you have one alarm name per line in your file, *without* any `["` or `"]` formatting, then you can have `jq` do the work of creating a JSON string with the list for you:

```
aws cloudwatch delete-alarms --alarm-names "$(jq -rn '[inputs]' <alarms.txt)"
```

No loop needed; just passing all the alarm names at once.